Synchronous FIFO design code review
As a personal project, I have designed a synchronous FIFO in Verilog HDL. But while testing with a testbench, I observed that the FIFO values are flushed out after one clock cycle when read-enable is triggered but not exactly when the read-enable is triggered (i.e., rd_en=1). I request some help in this case like why it is happening and how to fix it. I have pasted my console output here  and the waveforms output of DUT signals here:

I have used Siemens Questa 2023.3 Simulator from EDA playground.
Signals of the FIFO:
wr_data --> writes data into FIFO
wr_en   --> write enable, required to write data into FIFO
rd_data --> reads data from the FIFO
rd_en   --> read enable, required to read data from the FIFO
full    --> tells the status of FIFO is full or not
empty   --> tells the status of FIFO is empty or not
wr_ptr  --> write pointer
rd_ptr  --> read pointer
clk     --> clock
rst     --> reset
sync_fifo -> this is the actual FIFO memory

Verilog Design Code:
// Code your design here
module sync_fifo_design(wr_data,wr_en,rd_data,rd_en,full,empty,clk,rst);

//Input and Output declarations
parameter data_width = 8;
parameter depth = 256;
input [data_width-1:0]wr_data;
input wr_en,rd_en,clk,rst;
output reg [data_width-1:0]rd_data;
output reg full,empty;

//here address width i.e for pointers is logarithmically related to depth of fifo
reg [$clog2(depth)-1:0]wr_ptr,rd_ptr;
reg [data_width-1:0]sync_fifo[0:depth-1];

initial begin
wr_ptr=0;
rd_ptr=0;  
end

//full and empty conditions
always@(*) begin
if(rd_ptr==wr_ptr+1)
 full<=1'b1;
else
 full<=1'b0;

if(rd_ptr==wr_ptr)
  empty<=1'b1;
else
  empty<=1'b0;
end

//reset
always@(posedge clk) begin
if(rst) begin
 wr_ptr<=0;
 rd_ptr<=0;
 rd_data<=0;
end
end

//Writing data into fifo
always@(posedge clk) begin
if(wr_en && !full) begin
   sync_fifo[wr_ptr]<=wr_data;
   wr_ptr<=wr_ptr+1;
end
end

//read data from fifo
always@(posedge clk)begin
if(rd_en && !empty)begin
  rd_data<=sync_fifo[rd_ptr];
   rd_ptr<=rd_ptr+1;
end
end
endmodule

Testbench Code:
module tb();
 //input and output signals declaration
 parameter data_width = 8;
 reg [data_width-1:0]wr_data;
 reg wr_en,rd_en,clk,rst;
 wire [data_width-1:0]rd_data;
 wire full,empty;

 //module instantiation
sync_fifo_design dut(.wr_data(wr_data),.wr_en(wr_en),.rd_data(rd_data),.rd_en(rd_en),.full(full),.empty(empty),.clk(clk),.rst(rst));

 //stimuli
initial begin
 clk=0;
 rst=1;
 wr_en=0;
 rd_en=0;
 rst=0;
 //writing values 5,10,15,20 into FIFO

 @(posedge clk)wr_en=1;wr_data=3'b101;
 @(posedge clk)wr_data=4'b1010;
 @(posedge clk)wr_data=4'b1111;
 @(posedge clk)wr_data=5'b10100;
 @(posedge clk)wr_en=0;rd_en=1;
 end

 always
  #1 clk=~clk;
 initial begin
  $monitor("wr_data =%d,wr_en=%b,rd_en=%b,rst=%b,rd_data=%d",wr_data,wr_en,rd_en,rst,rd_data);
  $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;
  #30 $finish;
 end
endmodule


I'd rather not go through all that. But I can recommend that you read this page. It's excellent. You may also then want to consider this page when you get to the point of two different clock domains. ZipCPU is an exceptional source.

See, this is my implementation, and want to understand where I am going wrong for the unexpected behavior. There can be many designs but it doesn't mean I have to follow only them.

@aditya: What should I do when someone answers my question?

That's the way you designed it: rd_en goes high on one clock edge, and on the next clock edge, the FIFO sees it and reacts to it by outputting the data.
That's just the nature of synchronous design.
              :_______________                :__________
Clock   ______/               \_______________/
              : _________________________________________
rd_en   _______// goes high after clock edge  :
              :                               : _________
rd_data ---------------------------------------X_________
              ^                               ^
       FIFO sees rd_en low          FIFO sees rd_en high
         and does nothing             and reacts to it

Another way to put it is that even though you're simulating with zero delay in your logic, the simulator still treats the relationships among signal events as causal, meaning that it evaluates all of the effects of the rising edge of the clock (event #1) — both in the test bench and inside the FIFO — before it evaluates the effects of the rising edge of rd_en (event #2), because event #2 was caused by event #1.
If you want to create a "fall-through" FIFO in which the data is available sooner, and you "remove" the data using rd_en, it requires an extra register and some logic. That is, for example, how an AXI stream FIFO would work.

So you are saying that it is because of some propagation delay?

Not at all. It's built into the design. On one clock edge, you drive rd_en high. But as far as the FIFO is concerned, it has already seen rd_en low for that clock edge. The FIFO can't react to rd_en being high until the next clock edge, and that's what the simulation shows.

In addition to the explanation given in the other answer, there are other considerations.
I was unable to reproduce your results with two simulators other than the one you used.  The Cadence simulator produced unknown (x) values on your FIFO output signals.  The Synopsys simulator gave the result you were looking for.
This means that your Verilog code is not portable.  Ideally, the code should produce the same results on all simulators (assuming the simulator does not have a bug).  Your code does not adhere to good Verilog coding practices, either for simulation or synthesis.  For example, there is a race condition in the code which causes the different results between simulators.  In some cases, you are misusing blocking and nonblocking assignments.
I simplified the code, and it now produces the desired result on 3 simulators:
module sync_fifo_design(wr_data,wr_en,rd_data,rd_en,full,empty,clk,rst);

//Input and Output declarations
parameter data_width = 8;
parameter depth = 256;
input [data_width-1:0]wr_data;
input wr_en,rd_en,clk,rst;
output [data_width-1:0]rd_data;
output reg full,empty;

//here address width i.e for pointers is logarithmically related to depth of fifo
reg [$clog2(depth)-1:0]wr_ptr,rd_ptr;
reg [data_width-1:0]sync_fifo[0:depth-1];

//full and empty conditions
always@(*) begin
if(rd_ptr==wr_ptr+1)
 full=1'b1;
else
 full=1'b0;

if(rd_ptr==wr_ptr)
  empty=1'b1;
else
  empty=1'b0;
end

//Writing data into fifo
always@(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) begin
        wr_ptr<=0;
    end else if (wr_en && !full) begin
       sync_fifo[wr_ptr]<=wr_data;
       wr_ptr<=wr_ptr+1;
    end
end

//read data from fifo
assign rd_data = sync_fifo[rd_ptr];
always@(posedge clk)begin
    if (rst) begin
        rd_ptr<=0;
    end else if (rd_en && !empty)begin
        rd_ptr<=rd_ptr+1;
    end
end
endmodule


module tb();
 //input and output signals declaration
 parameter data_width = 8;
 reg [data_width-1:0]wr_data;
 reg wr_en,rd_en,clk,rst;
 wire [data_width-1:0]rd_data;
 wire full,empty;

 //module instantiation
sync_fifo_design dut(.wr_data(wr_data),.wr_en(wr_en),.rd_data(rd_data),.rd_en(rd_en),.full(full),.empty(empty),.clk(clk),.rst(rst));

 //stimuli
initial begin
 clk=0;
 rst=1;
 wr_en=0;
 rd_en=0;
 //writing values 5,10,15,20 into FIFO

 repeat (2) @(posedge clk); rst <= 0;
 @(posedge clk)wr_en <= 1;wr_data <= 3'b101;
 @(posedge clk)wr_data <= 4'b1010;
 @(posedge clk)wr_data <= 4'b1111;
 @(posedge clk)wr_data <= 5'b10100;
 @(posedge clk)wr_en <= 0;rd_en <= 1;
 end

 always
  #1 clk=~clk;

 initial begin
  $monitor("wr_data =%d,wr_en=%b,rd_en=%b,rst=%b,rd_data=%d",wr_data,wr_en,rd_en,rst,rd_data);
  $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;
  #30 $finish;
 end
endmodule

Here is the runnable code on EDA Playground.
It uses nonblocking assignments for all the synchronous inputs to the design in the testbench.  It uses blocking assignments for the combinational logic in the design.

Since the title of your question mentions you are seeking a code review, when you fix your Verilog code to yield the results you are looking for on your simulator, I recommend you then post your working code on the Code Review site.  You would receive an exhaustive review of the design and testbench code, which is beyond the scope of this site.
